# rotate ::before background image for label when checkbox is checked

Tags: css

I have a checkbox where I swapped out the checkbox itself for an image using ::before. I do this so I can toggle a div open and closed. This is working fine.

I would also like to rotate the image when the checkbox is checked, this is not working.

I created a codepen
https://codepen.io/justinblayney/pen/OJwRvBE

It is line 86 of the css in codepen where I am trying to target the ::before and rotate it

```
.filter-buttons #box:checked ~ .filter-checkbox::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```css
.filter-buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-buttons {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}
.filter-buttons .filter-dropbtn {
  background: #e0e1e1 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #2130b2;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Gibson;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 275px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-buttons .filter-dropbtn {
    width: 325px;
  }
}
.filter-buttons .filter-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-dropdown form .filter-checkbox::before {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 44px;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-dropdown form input {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content {
  background: #f0f0f0 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.16078);
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 275px;
  z-index: 100;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-buttons .filter-content {
    width: 325px;
  }
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content li::before {
  content: "";
  list-style: none;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2130b2;
  list-style: none;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content li a[href]:not(.button) {
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content li a[href]:not(.button):hover {
  color: #2130b2;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content li .parent {
  font: normal normal 600 20px/34px Gibson;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.filter-buttons .filter-content li .child {
  font: normal normal normal 20px/34px Gibson;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.filter-buttons #box:checked + .filter-content {
  display: block;
}
.filter-buttons #box:checked ~ .filter-checkbox::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-buttons">
  <div class="filter-dropdown">
      <form action="/form/submit" method="post">
        <a href="/blog/" title="All Blog Categories"><button class="filter-dropbtn">All Categories</button></a>
        <label for="box" class="filter-checkbox"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="box" />
        <ul class="filter-content">

            <li><a href="#">some content</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">more content</a></li>
          
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Could you put your code into your question, preferably as a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A Haworth
I did, it is in the codepen

Comment: A Haworth, before on this site they always asked you to make a codepen, so i did, looks like there is a built in one now

Comment: Move `<input>` before the `<label>` and change `+` in line 83 to `~` (tilde), already answered I see... BTW, have you checked the [The Details disclosure element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details)? This element has an *open/close mechanism* built in. Layout can be modified, nesting is also possible. Worth checking out the examples!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you swap the label and input, so the label comes after the input, the checked status of the input element can have an influence on the label.

However, the problem then is that the + you have (direct sibling) on the checked status of the input is not correct as the content is now not the immediate sibling.

Change it to a ~ (general sibling selector) and the list will appear.

```css
.filter-buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-buttons {
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
}

.filter-buttons .filter-dropbtn {
  background: #e0e1e1 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #2130b2;
  font: normal normal normal 20px/24px Gibson;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding-left: 25px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 275px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-buttons .filter-dropbtn {
    width: 325px;
  }
}

.filter-buttons .filter-dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-dropdown form .filter-checkbox::before {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 44px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  width: 44px;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-dropdown form input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content {
  background: #f0f0f0 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  border-radius: 0 0 20px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16078);
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0 10px 15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 275px;
  z-index: 100;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .filter-buttons .filter-content {
    width: 325px;
  }
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content li::before {
  content: "";
  list-style: none;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2130b2;
  list-style: none;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content li a[href]:not(.button) {
  color: #333;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content li a[href]:not(.button):hover {
  color: #2130b2;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content li .parent {
  font: normal normal 600 20px/34px Gibson;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.filter-buttons .filter-content li .child {
  font: normal normal normal 20px/34px Gibson;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.filter-buttons #box:checked~.filter-content {
  display: block;
}

.filter-buttons #box:checked~.filter-checkbox::before {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-buttons">
  <div class="filter-dropdown">
    <form action="/form/submit" method="post">
      <a href="/blog/" title="All Blog Categories"><button class="filter-dropbtn">All Categories</button></a>
      <input type="checkbox" id="box" />
      <label for="box" class="filter-checkbox"></label>
      <ul class="filter-content">

        <li><a href="#">some content</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">more content</a></li>

      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

You may want to do something about the double arrows being partially covered by the menu. Depends on your requirement.

Comment: thank A Haworth, (the double array covering is because the snippet is missing the full theme SCSS and doesn't appear 100% here)